# Dynamic Footer Size With Min Size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage with a footer (not fixed). The page's contents currently do not require scrolling and the footer currently takes up about 25% of the browser window at full screen on a 1920 x 1080 display. The footer's contents are aligned to the top of the footer and the rest of the footer is empty space but with the footer's color

It is very similar to this (my page is not wix though): http://www.wix.com/website-template/view/html/796?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wix.com%2Fwebsite%2Ftemplates%2Fhtml%2Fpersonal%2Fresume-cv%2F1&bookName=create-master-new&galleryDocIndex=2&category=personal&metaSiteId=&viewMode=desktop

Ideally, I would want that empty space in the footer to shrink as the page contents grows (instead of increasing the scrolling distance) but stop shrinking as it reaches a minimum height (and then the scrolling distance starts to increase)

My question is:

- is this possible with standard CSS?
- if not, is it possible with an existing JS library (e.g. jQuery)?
- if not, what is the best approach to writing the manual JS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have the following format

```
<div id="content">
   Content that could grow
</div>
<div id="footer">
   Footer
</div>
```

So in jQuery you could have a function that is called every time content is added to the `content` div or when the window is resized.

```
function fixFooter(){
    $('#footer').height( $(window).height() - $('#content').height() );
}
```

So every time there is change to the content div (added content or page resize), call `fixFooter()`.

But this could mean that footer's height could go to 0. So in your css put the following style for example:

```
#footer{
    min-height: 80px;
}
```